# Python retrieving data from web HTTP 400: Bad Request Error (Too many Requests?)

Tags: python, http

I am using a python module (googlefinance) to retrieve stock information. In my code, I create a symbols list which then gets sent into a loop to collect the information for each symbol.

The symbols list contains about 3000 indexes which is why I think I am getting this error. When I try shortening the range of the loop (24 requests), it works fine. I have tried also tried using a time delay in between requests but no luck. How can I make it so that I can retrieve the information for all specified symbols without getting the HTTP 400 Error?

```
from googlefinance import getQuotes
import pandas as pd
import pymysql
import time
import threading
import urllib.request

def createSymbolList(csvFile):
    df = pd.read_csv(csvFile)
    saved_column = df['Symbol']
    return saved_column

def getSymbolInfo(symbolList):
    newList=[]
    for i in range(int(24)):

        newList.append(getQuotes(symbolList[i]))

    return newList




nyseList = createSymbolList("http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=nyse&render=download")

try:
    l=(getSymbolInfo(nyseList))
    print(l)
    print(len(l))
except urllib.error.HTTPError as err:
    print(err)
```

Comment: a yahoo finance module exists to do the same task and I've always found it helpful, you could try either switching entirely to that module or splitting the load between them

Comment: @FindlaySmith Does the Yahoo Finance module have certain limit of requests that can be made? If not, where can I find this module?

Comment: Most of these services provide an API and offer an API Key. You should consider that, otherwise you're going to waste your time trying to jump through hoops to avoid it.

Comment: @l'L'l Is such there an API for Yahoo? I am trying to find it but for some reason when I create an Application on their site to retrieve the consumer key I don't see an option to be granted permission for Yahoo Finance.

Comment: the yahoo finance module isn't set up as an api it's as a module, so you need to run the command `sudo pip install yahoo_finance` , I've had the same problem in the past working with weather APIs but never with the finance module, which im running at the moment with a request rate of 3 every 2 seconds and im having no problems. Here's the yahoo_finance documentation: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yahoo-finance/1.3.2